# Custom Request class does not exist, yet it does?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out why my custom request class cannot be called by one of my methods.

I created my class with, `php artisan make:request ValidateUserSecretRequest`.

This created my custom request file in the `Http/Requests` folder as expected.

However, `ValidateUserSecretRequest` called within my `Auth\LoginController.php`, , I get `Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ValidateUserSecretRequest does not exist`.

Here's the controller, with unnecessary methods removed:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Cache;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use App\Http\Requests\ValidateSecretUserRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

public function postValidateToken(ValidateUserSecretRequest $request)
{
    // get user id and create cache key
    $userId = $request->session()->pull('2fa:user:id');
    $key = $userId . ':' . $request->totp;

    // use cache to store token to blacklist
    Cache::add($key, true, 4);

    // login and redirect user
    Auth::loginUsingId($userId);

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
}
```

And my custom request class:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Cache;
use Crypt;
use Google2FA;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidatonFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ValidateUserSecretRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     *
     * @var \App\User
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * Create a new FormRequest instance.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Validation\Factory $factory
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ValidatonFactory $factory)
    {

        $factory->extend(
            'valid_token',
            function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
                $secret = Crypt::decrypt($this->user->google2fa_secret);
                return Google2FA::verifyKey($secret, $value);
            },
            'Not a valid token'
        );

        $factory->extend(
            'used_token',
            function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
                $key = $this->user->id . ':' . $value;

                return !Cache::has($key);
            },
            'Cannot reuse token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        try {
            $this->user = User::findOrFail(
                session('2fa:user:id')
            );
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'totp' => 'bail|required|digits:6|valid_token|used_token',
        ];
    }

}
```

I've tried:

- composer dump-autoload
- composer update
- scratching my head multiple times
- recreating the custom request with artisan with a different name, same problem

What the hell is going on here?

Comment: I think you have a typo. In your controller you have written use `App\Http\Requests\ValidateSecretUserRequest;` whereas everywhere else you have written use `ValidateUserSecretRequest;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written "use App\Http\Requests\ValidateSecretUserRequest;" while you are using "ValidateUserSecretRequest" class, There is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Error in use App\Http\Requests\ValidateSecretUserRequest; You can check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You get `Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ValidateUserSecretRequest does not exist` since it doesn't really exists. `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\` prefix in the error means that it uses current namespace.

Look at `ValidateUserSecretRequest` - you should swap `User` and `Secret` to write correct class name.

Answer (score 0):

You have the class name wrong
You have it as
`App\Http\Requests\ValidateSecretUserRequest`; 
but actually it is `ValidateUserSecretRequest`